# Declaration of a variable in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand a C program and here is the following lines that I don't understand them:

```
static A B(float* array, int numel);
static int C(D_TYPE* array, int numel);
```

Is variable A declared to be a scalar and B is a matrix? Why there is no "," between A and B? Is array declared as a pointer?
In the second line, the variable "D_TYPE" is appeared for the first time. I assumed that this variable is imported from the header files, but I couldn't find it inside any other included files.

Comment: `A` is the return type of a function; `B` is the name of the function. About `D_TYPE` - obviously we can't tell you what's in your own program and header files; ask the person who wrote this.

Comment: They are funtion declarations

Comment: `A` is the return type of the function `B`, probably somewhere in the code you have a `struct A`. There is no `, ` between `A` and `B` because there shouldn't be one, it would be the same as writing `int , C`

Comment: The example is bad or unreal (guess it is school work). It is not normal to have type with name `A` and this is the confusing part.

Comment: I just changed the names to A, B, C and D for simplicity because the names were too long and I thought that it might be easier to represent them in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have 2 function declarations, both `B` and `C` are names of functions.

The first function returns a variable of type `static A` and takes as arguments a `float*` and an `int`

The second one returns a variable of type `static int` and takes as arguments a `D_TYPE*` and an `int`, you probably have `D_TYPE` defined somewhere in your code or in a header file somewhere. We don't know what this `D_TYPE` is but it could be either a `struct`, a `#define` or a `typedef`, this is the same for `A`.

These are only the declarations of the functions, somewhere in your code you will have

```
 static A B(float* array, int numel){
      //some code 
 }
```

and

```
static int C(D_TYPE* array, int numel){
      // some code
}
```

and these would be the definitions of the two functions

There isn't a `,` between `A` and `B` because that's just an error in `C (programming language not the function)`, it would be the same as writing

```
static int , C(D_TYPE* array, int numel);
```

in your second declaration and this is, of course, wrong

Comment: In function B, why is there an asterisk after the float?

Comment: @Akon `float *` means the argument is a `float pointer`, same thing for `D_TYPE *`. You are not actually passing to the function a `float` or a `D_TYPE` but a `pointer` to a `float` or `D_TYPE`

Answer (score 3):

The code tells that:

- Somewhere (rest of the code, header file, *whatever*) a **type** 'A' is (or should be) declared. Can be anything like a custom data structure (struct) or a numeric type defined via a **typedef**.
- B is a function (well actually a *prototype* of a function) that returns an 'A'. B takes a pointer to float (that by the name is implied to be an array, which in C are almost the same thing) and an integer as parameters. This is somewhat standard in C when you have to pass an array to a function.
- C is a function's prototype that states that function C returns an integer. As arguments it takes a pointer to 'D_TYPE', which, again is a type that is or should be defined somewhere, and an integer.
- static is used in both case probably to limit the visibility of the two functions only to the header file, which is unusual.

Personal considerations: names like 'a' or 'b' should be used only as argument values for very simple (not to say *stupid*) cases, like a Max(a, b) function or something similar.

Comment: "static is used in both case probably to limit the visibility of the two functions only to the header file"  What header file? `static` prototypes are common, but only in .c files.

Answer (score 1):

`static A B(float* array, int numel);`

`static` is storage class, refer [storage classes in c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Storage_class_specifiers)

`A` is a return type , that can vary from a primitive `int` , `char` to any complex `struct` type or even a pointer

`B` is name of fuction

`static int C(D_TYPE* array, int numel);`

here `C` is a function and `D_TYPE` is some type which might be `typedef`ed some where in your files

Answer (score 0):

You do not declare any variables here.

Both are function prototypes and `A` is the return type of the function `B`.